# Sending message through content script (1) -> background.js -> content script (2) cause Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I want to send message between two tabs with different urls. My general idea is using long-lived connections and passing message between two content scripts and one background.js:

On `www.website1.com` I inject content script (1) and run:

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "my_chanel"});
port.postMessage({file: 'some static message'});
```

This message will be handled by *background.js* - there I'll open new tab with `www.website2.org' and forward obtained message:

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(port => {
  if (port.name === "my_chanel") {
    port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {    // wait for message from content script (1)...
        if (msg?.file) {
            chrome.tabs.create({url:'www.website2.org'}, newTab => {    // if msg exist open new tab and forward msg
                const port = chrome.tabs.connect(newTab.id, {name: "my_chanel"});
                port.postMessage(msg);
            });
        } else {
            console.error('Service worker got empty message from 1st content script');
        }
    });
  }
});
```

Last, but not least - on `www.website2.org' I'll also run content script (2) which wait for message from *background.js*:

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "my_chanel"});
port.onMessage.addListener(msg => {
    console.log(msg.file);
});
```

Everything works except content script (2) - line `port.onMessage.addListener(...)` thrown an error:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist.

There is already described a bunch of similar problems, but all of them about simple one-time request (not long-lived like in my scenario) and asynchrous calls (I'm sending static text and there is no async calls).

There is no more details, I've disabled other extensions as well, for making sure that there is no interferention.

Can anyone told me where I made a mistake?

Comment: The content script is not yet running in the callback of chrome.tabs.create(), which is why connect() fails. You can store the value in chrome.storage instead or if you want messaging, just reverse the direction and call connect() from the content script in both cases, using different channel names.

Comment: True, after reversing the direction I was able to got my message in second content script. Thanks for help :)